# looping UPDATE syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am tweaking an example that I found at http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/10.html  to better suite my needs.  It's a big table of results that can be edited all in one shot instead of editing individual records.   I've modified the original to allow passing a search term to limit the contents of the table to a specific criteria.

I would greatly appreciate some help finding my typo.  In the initial query, $sql, I had to change the quotes a bit so it would work with my variable $location.  After updating some rows I hit submit and then just see the table headers and the submit button.  No content and no updates to the db.  The final update, $sql1, is very similar to the first so I'm not sure why it isn't working.  I'm trying to figure out if there isn't something wrong with the loop structure from the example.

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="*****"; // Mysql username 
$password="*****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="Inventory"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$location=$_POST['search']; 

echo $location; 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `Items` WHERE `Location` = "'.$location.'"';

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows 
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr> 
<td>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Present Condition</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Color</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td align="center">
<?php $id[]=$rows['ItemNumber']; ?> <?php echo $rows['ItemNumber']; ?>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="ItemName[]" type="varchar" id="ItemName" value="<?php echo $rows['ItemName']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<select name="ItemCondition[]" id="ItemCondition">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="Excellent">Excellent !</option>
    <option value="Good">Good</option>
    <option value="OK">OK</option>
    <option value="Poor">Below Average</option>
    <option value="Change">Replace</option>
   </select>

</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="ItemColor[]" type="varchar" id="ItemColor" value="<?php echo $rows['ItemColor']; ?>">

</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

<?php

// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
if($Submit){
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $sql1="UPDATE `Items` SET ItemName='$ItemName[$i]', ItemCondition='$ItemCondition[$i]', ItemColor='$ItemColor[$i]' WHERE ItemNumber='$id[$i]'";

    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    echo $i;
    }
}

if($result1){
header("location:inventory.php");
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

The table is very simple.  ItemNumber (the key), ItemName, ItemCondition, ItemColor.  Currently it queries the list of items, displays correctly the values of each item but then fails to update.  I'm stumped.

A million thanks in advance.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Where do you get the `$ItemName`, `$ItemCondition` and `$ItemColor` arrays from?  I cannot see them anywhere except in your final update query?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a couple issues with your code and reworked some of it for you. Hopefully the comments / code explain it, but feel free to ask any questions!

This isn't tested so I apologize in advance for any typos.

```php
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$db_name = "Inventory";

// When possible, you should use object-based SQL statements vs procedural
$sql = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if($sql->connect_error) {
    die($sql->connect_error);
}


// This should really be checked with isset()
// It should also be sanitized to prevent SQL injections
$location = $_POST['search']; // This field should be sanitized to prevent SQL injections

$get_items = $sql->query("
    SELECT *
      FROM `Items`
     WHERE `Location` = '".$location."'
");

// count
$count = $get_items->num_rows;

// NOTE: Notice that the Submit logic comes before some of the other logic
// This is because of the header() statement. You can't change location if you've already outputted code
// One method around this is to buffer, but in this case, it's easier to just shift the code
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $sql->query("
            UPDATE `Items`
               SET `ItemName`      = '".$_POST['ItemName'][$i]."',
                   `ItemCondition` = '".$_POST['ItemCondition'][$i]."',
                   `ItemColor`     = '".$_POST['ItemColor'][$i]."'
             WHERE `ItemNumber` = '".$_POST['id'][$i]."'
        ");
    }

    $sql->close(); // Close the connection on page-leave
    header("Location: inventory.php"); // Remember: You can't use this method to redirect if you've already displayed any content
    exit;
}
?>
<form name="form1" method="post">
    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Present Condition</th>
                <th>Color</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        while($row = $get_items->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <?php echo $row['ItemNumber']; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['ItemNumber']; ?>">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input name="ItemName[]" type="text" class="ItemName" value="<?php echo $row['ItemName']; ?>">
                <!-- This input type was "varchar" which isn't valid HTML -->
                <!-- Also, keep in mind that an ID should only be used once. Classes can be used multiple times, however. -->
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <select name="ItemCondition[]" id="ItemCondition">
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option value="Excellent">Excellent !</option>
                    <option value="Good">Good</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                    <option value="Poor">Below Average</option>
                    <option value="Change">Replace</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input name="ItemColor[]" type="text" class="ItemColor" value="<?php echo $row['ItemColor']; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
$sql->close(); // Close the connection when done executing queries
?>
```

Comment: Also note that you can get the value of the `<select />` by writing something like... `<option value="###"<?php if($row['ItemCondition'] == '###') echo ' selected'; ?>>xxx</option>`

Comment: I'm interested to find out more about your comment "When possible, you should use object-based SQL statements vs procedural", can you provide a reference with pros/cons regarding either method, or is this just a personal preference?

Comment: Thanks:  I'm checking this out once I'm at the office tomorrow.  I guess I don't have enough experience with the security issues but luckily this is for something that is completely internal and not facing the internet.  I found an example and did my best to modify it for my use.  The layout and logic was straight from the example I linked to.  I do see the logic and reason behind your explanation now.  THANKS

Comment: Just tested it and, using your code, the information is queried and displays properly but I'm still not getting any updates being made back to the db when the submit button is hit.  

I'm reading up on that header statement.  I haven't done this before and that came straight from the example. Both your code and mine seems to make logical sense (security issues aside) but I'm not understanding what is missing in the update statements.  It seems our arrays are formed differently so I have some more reading to do.